# Android how to move file from internal storage to external temporary folder?

Tags: android

hi i'm trying to open a doc file in quick office from my app but it doesn't seem to be allowed access to get the file from my internal storage. so what i'm wanting to do is move the file from internal storage to a temporary folder on the external storage so that when it can be opened by quick office? does anyone know if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

```
String source = // Internal file path
String destination = getExternalCacheDir() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
int total = 0;
while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
    total += len;
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
    if (total > 20 * 1024) {
        fos.flush();
    }
}
fis.close();
fos.close();
```